# My NQueens isSafeMove() function is constantly returning false

Tags: java, eclipse

My NQueens isSafeMove() function is constantly returning false and I cannot figure out why. I believe that it might have something to do with my checkLeft, checkUpperDiag, or checkLowerDiag but I don't see anything wrong with them. The isSafeMove checks to see whether the is a piece in the any movable distance of the queen, if there is return false, if there isn't then it should return true.

```
import java.awt.Point;
public class NQueensModel 
{
    private int myNumQueens;
    private boolean myBoard[][];
    private boolean mySolutionBoard [][];
    private String mySolutionBoardString [][];
    private int myNumSolutions;


NQueensModel(int nQueens)
{
    myNumQueens = nQueens;
    myBoard = new boolean [myNumQueens][myNumQueens];
    mySolutionBoard = new boolean [myNumQueens][myNumQueens];
    mySolutionBoardString = new String [myNumQueens][myNumQueens];
}

public boolean solvePuzzle()
{
    return solvePuzzle(0);
}

private boolean solvePuzzle(int ncolumn)
{
    if (ncolumn >= myNumQueens)
    {
        return true;
    }
    for(int i = 0; i < myNumQueens; i++)
    {
        if(this.isSafeMove(i, ncolumn) == true)
        {
            this.placeQueen(i, ncolumn);
            if(this.solvePuzzle(ncolumn + 1) == true)
            {
                return true;
            }
            this.removeQueen(i, ncolumn);
        }
    }
    return false;
}

public boolean isSafeMove(int row, int col)
{
    if(this.checkLeft(row, col) || this.checkUpperDiag(row, col)
            || this.checkLowerDiag(row, col) == true)
    {
        System.out.println("false");
        return false;
    }

    else 
    {
        System.out.println("true");
        return true;
    }
}

private boolean checkLeft(int row, int col)
{

    if(col >= myNumQueens || row >= myNumQueens)
    {
        return false;
    }
    if(row == 0)
    {
        return true;
    }
    for(int i= col - 1 ; i >= 0; i--)
    {
        if(myBoard[row][i] == true)
        {
            return false;
        }
        if(i == 0)
        {
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}

private boolean checkUpperDiag(int row, int col)
{
    if(col == 0 || row == 0)
    {
        return true;
    }
    for(int i = row, j = col; row >= 0 || col >= 0; row--, col--)
    {
        if(myBoard[row][col] == true)
        {
            return false;
        }
        if(col == 0 && row == 0)
        {
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}

private boolean checkLowerDiag(int row, int col)
{
    if(col == 0 || row == myNumQueens - 1)
    {
        return true;
    }
    for(int i = row, j = col; row < myNumQueens || col < myNumQueens; row--, col++)
    {
        if(myBoard[row][col] == true)
        {
            return false;
        }
        if(col == 0 && row == myNumQueens - 1)
        {
            return true;
        }
    }

    return false;
}



public boolean placeQueen(int row, int col)
{
    if(myBoard[row][col] == false)
    {
        myBoard[row][col] = true;
        return false;
    }
    return false;
}


public String getMySolutionBoardString()
{
    for(int col = 0; col < myNumQueens; col++)
    {
        for(int row = 0; row < myNumQueens; row++)
        {
            if(myBoard[col][row] == true)
            {
                mySolutionBoardString[row][col] = "Q";
            }
            else
            {
                mySolutionBoardString[row][col] = "-";
            }
            System.out.print(mySolutionBoardString[row][col] + " ");
        }
        System.out.println("");
    }
    return null;
}

private boolean removeQueen(int row, int col)
{
    myBoard[row][col] = false;
    return false;
}

public boolean getQueenOnBoard(Point point)
{
    return myBoard[(int)point.getX()][(int)point.getY()];
}

public String toString()
{
    String string = this.getMySolutionBoardString();
    return string;
}
```

}

Comment: What happens when you run this code with a debugger (most modern Java IDE's have debugger capabilities)?

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels yes after it goes through checkLeft it doesnt even bother to go through any of the other checks.

Answer (score 0):

In your loop

```
for(int i = 0; i < myNumQueens; i++)
{
    if(this.isSafeMove(i, ncolumn) == true)
    {
        this.placeQueen(i, ncolumn);
        if(this.solvePuzzle(ncolumn + 1) == true)
        {
            return true;
        }
        this.removeQueen(i, ncolumn);
    }
}
```

Think about it when you call isSafeMove (i,ncolumn) the first time i = 0 so checkLeft will return true and every iteration after that ncolumn = 0 so your calls to checkUpperDiag () and checkLowerDiag () will return true, so those methods returning true every time means isSafeMove will return false every iteration of your loop

Comment: I endned up fixing my problem i have another question though, How would I print out the number of solutions for each nQueens problem. for instance since 8x8 has 92 solutions i would print out, 8-nQueens: 92 solutions.

Comment: I dont know, use your toString method i guess, you should just ask another question if you have one